# What is the spatial counterpart of proper time?

Tags: special-relativity

Proper time is an invariant quantity. Is there a spatial counterpart of proper time in special relativity, or anything similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [proper length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_length), the spacial distance between two points measured in the rest frame.

Comment: Thanks, is it also an invariant quantity like proper time?

Comment: Yes, it is frame invariant.